# Error when building llvm x-ray instrument

Tags: llvm, llvm-gcc

Following the instructions from [llvm XRay instrument guide](https://llvm.org/docs/XRayExample.html), I am stuck on the part

`cmake -GNinja ../llvm -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="-fxray-instrument" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fxray-instrument" \`

as it is giving me `c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-fxray-instrument`.

I have already built the latest llvm project which has the XRay in the tool directory and I used the "Unix Makefiles" option instead of Ninja.

Comment: use -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/clang and  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/clang++  flags with cmake.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first sentence says

> To debug an application with XRay instrumentation, we need to build it with a Clang that supports the -fxray-instrument option.

You, obviously, are using non-clang compiler, which doesn't support this option flag.